# asterisk how to create outbound calls

Tags: sip, asterisk, outbound

I have a sip server. In the extensions.conf i've set the following:

```
[extensions.conf]

exten =>1,1,Dial(SIP/1,20,tr)
exten => 1,n,Hangup()

exten => 2,1,Dial(SIP/2,20,tr)
exten => 2,n,Hangup()
```

I need to be able to `have outbound calls`. I mean from `client 1` I want to call a client on a different sip server. How to set that in the extensions.conf file?

Need help.Appreciiate

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way is:

```
exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/192.168.1.1/${EXTEN})
```

But better answer is : read O'Relly book first.